# How to perform complex rules system using OAuth2/OpenId?

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid, claims-based-identity, identityserver3

I am looking into building a REST service as back-end and I was looking into OAuth2/OpenId to handle the security, but I'm not sure how to fit my complex structure into the rules or scopes structure.

Nothing is build yet, so maybe my reasoning is wrong and the domain model can be modified to match my needs, or OAuth2/OpenId is not suited for me.

I have a domain model as follows:

- A **Country**.
- A **Region**, which is linked to a Country. A single Country holds multiple Regions, but a Region belongs only to one Country.
- A **Product** which is linked to one Country, and optionally one Region.
- An **Action** which can be performed on a Product. (Not linked to a Product directly, rather CRUD related stuff.)
- A **Profile** which is linked to a Country, optionally a Region, and which holds the list of Actions.
- A **User** which is linked to one or more Profiles.

A User can request a list of Products. On those Products, he can perform Actions based on what his Profile allows, thus if the Country/Region of the Product matches the Profile Country/Region.

Imagine:

```
Product | Country | Region
--------------------------
      A |       X |      Z
      B |       X |      Y

Profile | Country | Region | Action
-----------------------------------
      I |       X |      Z | UPDATE
      I |       X |      Z | DELETE
      J |       X |      Y | DELETE
```

The user is linked to Profile I and J.

- If the user selects Product A, then he is allowed to UPDATE the Product, because the Country X and Region Z match.
- If the user selects Product B, then he is *not* allowed to UPDATE the Product, because even though Country X matches, Region Y does not match Profile I.

And this is my problem. I don't quite understand how I can achieve this complex rule system using the basic rules and scopes OAuth2/OpenId provides. Most samples use a very simple concept, basic CRUD allow or not, but I require another hierarchical level.

And simply using the system to authenticate a user and then still having to perform an in-depth action validation call each time seems overhead. Then I might simply skip OAuth2/OpenId and perform my own validation.

Or is there another way I can model my requirements to fit OAuth2/OpenId's concept?

Answer (score 1):

OpenID Connect is an authentication protocol on top of the more general token request protocol OAuth 2.0.

They have nothing to do with how you implement authorization / business rules.

Furthermore the outcome of OIDC/OAuth is identity data, scopes and maybe coarse grained identity data. The `ClaimsPrincipal` is **not** a dumping ground for arbitrary authorization data.

Authorization is done based on the incoming identity, there is no special "technology" or "protocol" used for it. One popular approach is "resource-based authorization". This has been built into the new asp.net core - but otherwise is not hard to implement yourself.

https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authorization/resourcebased.html

Comment: Resource-based authorization seems a nice solution to handle things on the server side. Unfortunately, it still leaves me with the question on how to handle this on the client side. If a user selects a row in the table I'd like to update the UI action buttons without having to make a call to the REST service each time, asking "Do I have permission?". Any suggestions?

Comment: I do not do much client development. My main point was - this is unrelated to OAuth/OpenId Connect

Comment: Provided that every action/request coming from the client has to be double-checked on the server (e.g. can this user perform this action on this row in this table?), re. client side: when server first provides client with the tabular data (whether its a MVC View filled with data, or a REST API returning JSON), that tabular data should also hold allowed actions for that user, for each row. Then it's responsibility of Razor template or JS SPA not to allow those actions on those rows

Answer (score 0):

I would put all those info (country, region,profile,actions) as clams in ClaimsPrincipal and then use information from claims of current user to detect has user privileges or not to perform action